# How to include multiple child objects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing with new ASP.Net 5.0 WebApi and strugling to understand how to return more then one child object, or child of the child.

Lets say I have 4 classes:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public int ColourId { get; set; }

    public virtual Type Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Colour Colour { get; set; }
}

public class Type
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual TypeGroup TypeGroup { get; set; }
}

public class Colour
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TypeGroup
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And would like to return all the data for the car including Type, Colour, and even TypeGroup of the Type. How do I Do it?

When I do like this it includes only Type:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Car> Get()
    {
        return _dbContext.Cars.Include(c => c.Type);
    }
```

This is my setup in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });
```

Is it possible to set to return every child object and grandchild  and etc?

Many thanks

Comment: you can chain `Include()`'s together for each navigation property.

Comment: but if I will have 30 child, I would have to do it 30 times? Or is there a way to set it to include all?

Comment: You can turn off lazyloading for all entities by using: `this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` see here [lazy loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx). You can also remove `virtual` from the property declaration/

Comment: Thank you. if you put this on the answers, I can mark it as answered

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried it and did it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off lazy loading for all entities by using the following in your `DbContext` class (place this in the constructor):

`this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

This will disable it for all entities - so be wary of this and watch for performance issues.

Another way you can load all the entities for a particular class is to remove the `virtual` keyword from the property declarations.